# JOOQ listeners: context data is not cleaned between two queries

Tags: java, jooq, micronaut, micrometer

In my current project, I use java 11/JOOQ 3.15/Micronaut/Micrometer. In order to have relevant SQL metrics, I would like to put a name on my JOOQ queries.

To do that, I have tried to use the `ctx.data()` field combined with a custom ExecuteListener.

Let's take a really simplified listener:

```java
@Singleton
public class JooqListener extends DefaultExecuteListener {

    transient StopWatch watch;
    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    public JooqListener(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void executeStart(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        watch = new StopWatch();
    }

    @Override
    public void fetchEnd(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        Tags prometheusTag = Tags.of("queryName", ctx.configuration().data("queryName").toString());
        meterRegistry.timer("sql.query.timer", prometheusTag)
            .record(watch.split(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }
    // I have tried to remove the data manually, but not working
    @Override
    public void end(ExecuteContext ctx) {
        ctx.configuration().data().remove("queryName");
    }
}
```

If I send 2 different queries from two different repositories, like for example:

```java
DSLContext context = DSL.using(jooqConfiguration);
context.data("queryName", "query1");
return context.select(1).from("dual").fetch();
```

And just after, let say I'm not attentive and I forgot to name my query:

```java
DSLContext context = DSL.using(jooqConfiguration);
return context.select(2).from("dual").fetch();
```

`ctx.configuration().data("queryName")` in my listener will always contain "query1", which I didn't expect because ExecuteListeners are listening query by query, and furthermore, I have created two different DSLContexts. It looks like the `ctx.data()` cannot be cleaned but just overwritten.

Is it an expected behaviour? Is there an other object/method I should use which can be limited to the query scope? (I searched a lot on google but "data" keyword is a little bit annoying...)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DSLContext` just wraps a `Configuration`. It doesn't have its own lifecycle. So, if you're modifying the `Configuration.data()` map through `DSLContext`, you're modifying a globally shared object. In other words, you must not modify `Configuration.data()` except for when you initialise your configuration for the first time. [See this section of the manual for more details](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/).

A better way to do what you intend to do is:

```java
// Create a "derived" configuration, which is a new, 
// independent Configuration instance
DSLContext context = DSL.using(jooqConfiguration.derive());
context.data("queryName", "query1");
return context.select(1).from("dual").fetch();
```

And then, in your `ExecuteListener`:

```java
@Override
public void fetchEnd(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    // Reading the Configuration.data() is still fine:
    Tags prometheusTag = Tags.of("queryName", 
        ctx.configuration().data("queryName").toString());
    meterRegistry.timer("sql.query.timer", prometheusTag)
        .record(watch.split(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}

@Override
public void end(ExecuteContext ctx) {
    // But you shouldn't modify it
    ctx.configuration().data().remove("queryName");
}
```

Comment: Perfectly woking, thank you! My problem was exactly what you said: my jooqConfiguration was a bean shared all across my application. 
No more issue using `derive()`, I removed the `.data().remove(...)`.
Impressed by your implication in stackoverflow and proud to receive an answer from you for my first post! :)